# Global variable in Marko JS Template and Express

Tags: node.js, marko

Once I set a global variable in Express using

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = true;
  next();
});
```

How can I get that variable from inside any view (*.marko template)?

I know in Jade you should be able to access it directly like any other variable, without the need to pass it from child to parent template. What's the equivalent in Marko JS?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

With Marko you typically want to [bypass the Express view engine](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/bypassing-express-view-rendering-for-speed-and-modularity/) and render a template directly to the writable `res` stream:

```
var template = require('./template.marko');

app.use(function(req, res){
  var templateData = { ... };
  template.render(templateData, res);
});
```

With that approach you have full control over what data is passed to your template. Technically, you have access to `res.locals` in your template by doing the following:

```
<div if="out.stream.locals.isAuthenticated">
```

NOTE: `out.stream` is simply a reference to the writable stream that is being written to (in this case, `res`)

You have some other options:

***Use `res.locals` as template data***

```
var template = require('./template.marko');

app.use(function(req, res){
  var templateData = res.locals;
  template.render(templateData, res);
});
```

***Build template data from `res.locals`***

```
var template = require('./template.marko');

app.use(function(req, res){
  var templateData = {
    isAuthenticated: res.locals.isAuthenticated
  };
  template.render(templateData, res);
});
```

Marko also supports "global" data that is accessible using `out.global`. See: http://markojs.com/docs/marko/language-guide/#global-properties

If you still have questions then please share!

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Steele-Idem, the only thing I had to do apart from the code I wrote on my post was to check the variable with `if="out.stream.locals.isAuthenticated"` as you said. Nothing more! This way I don't have to pass the variable directly to the template as the other examples you suggested. What about `app.locals` ? How can I reach those?

Comment: Hey @crash, the `app` instance hangs off of `res` and `req` as `res.app` and `req.app`, respectively, so you can access `app.locals` as `out.stream.app.locals`.

Comment: For people like me who arrived here and found a dead link :
we can access req, res, app, app.locals, and res.locals automatically by out.global in any view by using res.marko instead of template.render with express. 
See https://markojs.com/docs/express/#usage